ArrayList Error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:"
I have been writing this code to allow 2 .txt files to be read in into an array list and have their values stored so i can output them, but on every run, it gives me this error. I tried as much as i could as this is my first time learning java and this section in my class in particular.
#vehichles.txt
#type   Name    starting location (they have to start somewhere)
train Express Kyton
train Shinkansen Dolton
air PuddleJumper Edwards
water Trident Haltom
water fune Islando
road Rider Abaca
road Ronin Brecha
road RoadWarrior Gram
road Hotrod Edwards
road DieselBuddy Jeku

and #cargo.txt
#time,  name,   source, destination,    wt
1 Bob's Cargo Abaca Dolton 1
1 Bob's Cargo Nandai Oda 3
1 ABC Chemicals Jeku Edwards 18
1 InterPlast Kyton Midoria 4
2 Bob's Cargo Fiskal Brecha 2
2 IIAE Oda Abaca 1
2 ABC Chemicals Jeku Lydia 14
2 Nautalis LLC Islando Haltom 1
2 Nautalis LLC Islando Edwards 2
2 Bob's Cargo Abaca Midoria 1
2 IIAE Chiano Kyton 2
2 Ryder Systems Edwards Dolton 1
2 Live Automotives Gram Jeku 2
3 EMCOR Holdings Edwards Kyton 47
3 IIAE Lydia Fiskal 2
3 Bob's Cargo Abaca Haltom 7
4 IIAE Oda Chiano 2
4 EMCOR Holdings Abaca Edwards 22
4 Bob's Cargo Oda Kyton 2
4 ABC Chemicals Jeku Edwards 9
4 InterPlast Kyton Midoria 4
5 Bob's Cargo Fiskal Brecha 3
5 Nautalis LLC Islando Abaca 1
5 ABC Chemicals Jeku Islando 3
6 InterPlast Abaca Midoria 4
6 ABC Chemicals Brecha Lydia 2

I have tried making sure there where no errors I was personally aware of and even making sure the path to the file was correct, but I'm not sure whether that's what's giving me the error if it's something completely different.
this is the code of what I have for now
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Cargo {
    int time;
    String name;
    String source;
    String destination;
    int weight;

    public Cargo(int time, String name, String source, String destination, int weight) {
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    String type;
    String name;
    String startingLocation;

    public Vehicle(String type, String name, String startingLocation) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.startingLocation = startingLocation;
    }
}

class CargoDataReader {
    ArrayList<Cargo> cargoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void readCargoFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            Cargo cargo = new Cargo(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
            cargoList.add(cargo);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    public void readVehicleFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
            vehicleList.add(vehicle);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}

public class Array_Lab {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    
    {
        CargoDataReader reader = new CargoDataReader();
        reader.readCargoFile("#cargolist.txt");
        reader.readVehicleFile("#vehicles.txt");
        
        System.out.println("Cargo List:");
        for (Cargo cargo : reader.cargoList) {
            System.out.printf("Time: %d, Name: %s, Source: %s, Destination: %s, Weight: %d%n", 
                              cargo.time, cargo.name, cargo.source, cargo.destination, cargo.weight);
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nVehicle List:");
        for (Vehicle vehicle : reader.vehicleList) {
            System.out.printf("Type: %s, Name: %s, Starting Location: %s%n", 
                              vehicle.type, vehicle.name, vehicle.startingLocation);
        }
    }
}

